# How to map/assign/replace values of one dictionary to another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Say I have the following 3 dictionaries:

```
General case:

d1 = {'c_choice1': '1.10', 'c_choice2': '1.20',...}
d2 = {'John': {'strength': 'choice1', 'agility': 'choice2',...},...}
d3 = {'John': {'choice1': 'c_choice1', 'choice2': 'c_choice2',...},...}

d2 and d3 can be:

d2 = {'John': {'strength': 'choice1', 'agility': 'choice2'}, 'Kevin': {'int': 'choice1'}}
d3 = {'John': {'choice1': 'c_choice1', 'choice2': 'c_choice2'}, 'Kevin': {'choice1': 'c_choice1'}}

or

d2 = {'John': {'strength': 'choice1', 'agility': 'choice1'}}
d3 = {'John': {'choice1': 'c_choice1'}}
```

What I want to do (using general case as example):

a) from d3, let choice1 = c_choice1, choice2 = c_choice2, etc.

```
choice1 = c_choice1
choice2 = c_choice2
```

b) lookup d1 and find the value for c_choice1, c_choice2, etc.

```
c_choice1 = 1.10
c_choice2 = 1.20
```

c) create a final dictionary with choice1, choice2, etc in d2 replaced with the value in d1

My desired output (using general case as example):

```
d4 = {'John': {'strength': '1.10', 'agility': '1.20',...}...}
```

Note:

a) the 3 dictionaries are created when extracting the data from a input file, the keys and values are not defined by myself, hence I do not know the order of the keys and values in the dictionaries.

b) I am using Python 2.7.

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated version:  Based on the info given in the comments, I have modified my solution to handle multiple instances of the same choice value, or missing instances, in `d2`.  Here is the new solution, which I believe will do what was requested.  I have modified the sample data to exercise the new functionality:

```
d1 = {'c_choice1': '1.10', 'c_choice2': '1.20'}
d2 = {'John': {'strength': 'choice1', 'agility': 'choice1'}}
d3 = {'John': {'choice1': 'c_choice1', 'choice2': 'c_choice2'}}

d4 = {}
for k in d3:
    d2x = d2[k]
    d3x = d3[k]

    d2y = {v: [] for x in (d2x.values(), d3x.keys()) for v in x}
    for k2 in d2x:
        d2y[d2x[k2]].append(k2)

    d4x = {v2 : d1[d3x[k3]] for k3 in d3x for v2 in d2y[k3]}
    d4[k] = d4x
```

Here is what `d4` looks like:

```
{'John': {'agility': '1.10', 'strength': '1.10'}}
```

Note that `choice1` occurs twice in `d2`, and `choice2` is absent.

Comment: Thanks. However, if my `d2` and `d3` is in this form: `d2 = {'John': {'strength': 'choice1', 'agility': 'choice1'}}`, `d3 = {'John': {'choice1': 'c_choice1'}}` and my desired output is `{'John': {'agility': '1.10', 'strength': '1.10'}}`, what changes should I make? I have tried using your code but it doesn't work.

Comment: d3 can be `d3 = {'John': {'choice1': 'c_choice1', 'choice2': 'c_choice2'}}` even `choice2` is not found in `d2`

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear from the original post that `choice1` can appear multiple times in `a given entry in `d2`.  I'll take a look and see if I can modify this.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have edited my post and gave some examples showing that the dictionaries can be in many different forms.

Comment: Ok, I have modified my solution.  I believe it now does everything that you want.  Please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Oops, sorry, my first re-post had a typo in it (I was unintentionally reusing `k`).  Please try the version that's there now.

Comment: Yes, everything works now. Thank you very much. I will take my time to fully understand your code and will ask you again if I have any questions.

Comment: Great, glad it's working for you!  If you have questions later just post them here.

Comment: Also, make sure the version you picked up works when there's more than one name.  I pasted an intermediate version shortly before the final version that had a variable conflict problem.  The latest version uses `k3` in the assignment to `d4x`, so you can check that.

Comment: Hi Tom, could you please try and see whether you can help me on my latest question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080975/python-writing-multiple-nested-dictionaries-in-one-table-in-a-text-file-separat)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this as a single nested dict comprehension:

```
d4 = {name: {stat: d1[d3[name][choice]]
             for name, choices in d2.items()
             for stat, choice in stats.items()}
      for name, stats in d2.items()}
```

but that's almost impossible to understand. Instead, a loop and a dict comp works well:

```
d4 = {}
for name, stats in d2.items():
    d4[name] = {stat: d1[d3[name][choice]] for name, choices in d2.items()
                                           for stat, choice in stats.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, if my `d2` and `d3` is in this form: `d2 = {'John': {'strength': 'choice1', 'agility': 'choice2'}, 'Kevin': {'int': 'choice1'}}`, `d3 = {'John': {'choice1': 'c_choice1', 'choice2': 'c_choice2'}, 'Kevin': {'choice1': 'c_choice1'}}` and my desired output is: `{'John': {'agility': '1.20', 'strength': '1.10'}, 'Kevin': {'int': '1.10'}}`, what changes should I make? I have tried using your code but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the keys and use then to extract data. for example:

**In order to extract the names from d2:**

```
for name in d2:
    print name
```

> **output**:
>    John

**Extract the dictionary for each name:**

```
for name  in d2:
    for choice in d2[name]:
        print choice
```

> **output**:
>    agility 
>   strength