# Python: Writing multiple nested dictionaries in one table in a text file separated by tab

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, string-formatting

I am new to Python and I am struggling with printing multiple nested dictionaries in one table separated by tab.

I wrote a script to read data from an input file and store the data in 3 different dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'Ben': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'}, 'Tom': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
d2 = {'Ben': {'Strength': 'wo_mana', 'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Speed': 'wo_mana'}, 'Tom': {'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Agility': 'wo_mana'}}
d3 = {'Ben': {'Strength': '1.10', 'Int': '1.20', 'Speed': '1.50'}, 'Tom': {'Int': '1.40', 'Agility': '1.60'}}
```

I want to represent the data in a table format and when opened in Excel, it looks something like this:

```
Name Skill Magic wo_mana          wi_mana
Ben  true  false Strength = 1.10  Int = 1.20
                 Speed = 1.50
Tom  true  true  Agility = 1.60   Int = 1.40
```

So my desired output in the output file should be like this:

```
Name\tSkill\tMagic\two_mana\twi_mana
Ben\ttrue\tfalse\tStrength = 1.10\tInt = 1.20
\t\t\tSpeed = 1.50\t
Tom\ttrue\ttrue\tAgility = 1.60\tInt = 1.40
```

I am aware that I could do this using the `csv` module but it looks like it wouldn't make sense for multiple rows for a record in `csv` so I have decided to try `string formatting`.

I tried my best and this is what I have written so far:

```
print('Name\tSkill\tMagic\two_mana\twi_mana\n')
for key in d1:
    print('%s\t%s\t%s' %(key, d1[key]['Skill'], d1[key]['Magic']))
```

and it works well for the first 3 columns, `Name, Skill and Magic`.

My question is how am I supposed to print the `wo_mana` and `wi_mana` data into the same table? Should I change my dictionaries to:

```
d1 = {'Ben': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'}, 'Tom': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
d23 = {'Ben': {'wo_mana': 'Strength = 1.10', 'wi_mana': 'Int = 1.20', 'wo_mana': 'Speed = 1.50'}, 'Tom': {'wi_mana': 'Int = 1.40', 'wo_mana': 'Agility = 1.60'}}
```

so that they are easier to print with `string formatting`?

**EDIT**:

If my dictionaries is in this form:

```
d123 = {'Ben': {'wo_mana': ['Strength = 1.10', 'Speed = 1.50'], 'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.20'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'},
        'Tom': {'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.40'], 'wo_mana': ['Agility = 1.60'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
```

would it be easier?

I tried to write my code for `d123` but it is still not working for me:

```
for key in d123_new:
    print('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' %(d123_new[key]['Skill'], d123_new[key]['Magic'], x for x in d123_new[key]['wo_mana'], y for y in d123_new[key]['wi_mana']))
```

Please show me how to print the data in the table format that I mentioned above, I have tried everything that I could think of, any help would be greatly appreciated!